# 'ScaleTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView'

Tags: wpf, xaml

Whay I give that error "'ScaleTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView'." when ScaleTransform in another trigger, but whe I set it in Image.Triggers it work fine?

```
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding Source}" Height="128" Width="128" Focusable="True">
                                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" CenterX="25" CenterY="25" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                                    </Image>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListView.SelectionChanged">
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="myBeginStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ListView.Triggers>
                    </ListView>
```

and I try that but also not working:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding Source}" Height="128" Width="128" Focusable="True">
                                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" CenterX="25" CenterY="25" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                                    </Image>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListView.SelectionChanged">
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="myBeginStoryboard">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding MyAnimatedScaleTransform}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding MyAnimatedScaleTransform}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ListView.Triggers>
                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that controllers in DataTemplate cannot be accessed, so i change my cod Xaml to:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding Source}" Height="128" Width="128" Focusable="True">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" CenterX="25" CenterY="25" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseDown">
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="myBeginStoryboard">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now I have been returned to my main problem, when I click second time on image before first animation be ended (Reverse), the image don't revert to original size.

Comment: <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop"> should fix your issue